# How to convert SQL query to CakePHP query

Tags: cakephp

I have following query where `interest` is field name. `interest` contains like football,vollyball etc.

```
SELECT * FROM `drop_down_multiples` where find_in_set('football',`interest`);
```

I stuck to convert above query in `CakePHP`. How I can convert ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this :-

cakephp haven't any function for this,you have to do some tricks that how cakephp built the 
sql queries from their syntax.

```
$this->DropDownMultiples->find('all',array(
  'conditions'=>array('FIND_IN_SET("'.$search_field.'",DropDownMultiple.interest)‌​')
  ));
```

Comment: What you mean by `place_here_list`?

Comment: You have to change something like this `'conditions'=>array('FIND_IN_SET("'.$search_field.'",DropDownMultiple.interest)')`

Comment: @Sadikhasan In which `interest` field has to be searched

Comment: You are nearest the solution but you have to change your syntax of `find_in_set` I mentioned above

Comment: do you mean DropDownMultiple.interest having comma separated values.you should mention in the question.

Comment: Are you understand I placed query with `$condition` above?

Comment: `place_here_list` is what according to my question?

Comment: @Sadikhasan I posted according to `FIND_IN_SET` syntax since you didn't mentioned clearly in the question.also you can manipulate from here.

Comment: I posted answer also you are correct and I got solution! Thanks

Comment: -1 (for now) That smells like a nice SQL injection vulnerability. You should use the proper array syntax so that the input is being escaped properly: ``'conditions' => array('FIND_IN_SET(?, `Model`.`field`)' => $searchTerm)`` @Sadikhasan

Comment: @Sadikhasan I'm not a psychic, you have to show that error and your exact code, but that's not really something to be discussed in the comments, instead RajeevRanjan should update his answer with the proper code, and in the mean time you should study the docs on how to properly use the array syntax: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions**

Comment: @ndm this is my code `array('FIND_IN_SET(?,DropDownMultiple.interest)'=>$this->params->query['interest'])` and it put `=` sign after sql query

Comment: @Sadikhasan There are invisible characters in your code (`U+200B` and `U+200C`) that break the query, they are already present in Rajeev Ranjans example code, I really don't know how he managed to slip that in. Copy the code from my comment, it should work fine.

Comment: @Sadikhasan It works fine for me, so again, please read the docs on how to use the array syntax. No offense, but I don't have time for guiding you by hand right now.

Comment: @ndm how late binding prevent from sql injection because at the last both ways create same sql statement for execution .

Comment: Populate the `$search_field` variable with a value like `some"value` and you'll see the difference...