# Error with Find query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

**CakePHP Code**

```
$data = $this->DropDownMultiple->find('all',array(
            'conditions'=>array('FIND_IN_SET(?,DropDownMultiple.interest)' => array('football')),
            'order'=>'created_on desc'
            )
        );
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT DropDownMultiple.*
FROM `cakephp_tutorial`.`drop_down_multiples` AS `DropDownMultiple`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('football',`DropDownMultiple`.`interest`) =
ORDER BY `created_on` DESC
```

**Syntax Error**

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY `created_on` desc' at line 1

Problem is insert `=` sign at the end of where condition. Why this happen? Where am I wrong? help me.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545045/how-to-use-find-in-set-in-cakephp-find-method

Comment: @joshua.paling If I put direct value in `find_in_set` then it work fine but parametrized will not work

Comment: @Sadikhasan whatever ndm suggested on your previous question not working for me too .

Comment: @RajeevRanjan Yes you are right! I also checked for different ways but it not work.

Comment: Guys, what I've shown you definitely works! @Sadikhasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [**the code that I've posted**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624233/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-cakephp-query/24624359#comment38171680_24624359) in the comments of the original questions answer?

You seem to have managed to remove [**the hidden chars that I've mentioned**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624233/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-cakephp-query/24624359#comment38173098_24624359), at least they are not present in the code you are showing here anymore, not sure about the code that you are actually using though.

However, you are not using the format that I've shown you:

```
$data = $this->DropDownMultiple->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'FIND_IN_SET(?, `DropDownMultiple`.`interest`)' => 'football'
        ),
        'order' => 'created_on desc'
    )
);
```

Note the quotes around the model and field name, and most important, the space after the `,`.
Requiring that space might be a bug in CakePHP, not sure.

Also note that there's no need to wrap the value into an array, even though it works in case it contains only a single entry.