# How to add the caret in the navbar in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I am new to Cakephp and I have created code for the Navigation Bar of my site.

But, the problem is, I fetched the Navbar menu from database and I wanna add the dropdown caret after the value fetched.

My Code is :

```
echo "<li class='dropdown'>".$this->Html->link($statmenu['Menu']['name'],'');
```

Where and How should I add this `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-caret"></span>` code for caret ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "<li class='dropdown'>".$this->Html->link(
  '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-caret"></i><span>'.$statmenu['Menu']['name'].'</span>','',array('escape'=>false)
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, Bro ! The symbol is not showing. But, no error too.

Comment: Can you give me HTML generated code for given cakephp code?

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">MENU <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">dmenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dmenu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dmenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

Comment: You are not updated code with my current code check with given my code.

Comment: No, Bro ! We copied and pasted your updated code. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no `<i>` tag in your html code which is I puted in my answer.

Comment: echo "<li class='dropdown'>".$this->Html->link(
  '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-caret"></i><span>'.$statmenu['Menu']['name'].'</span>','',array('escape'=>false)
  );

Comment: @BenedictRuban There are invisible chars in your code (`U+200B` and `U+200C`), apply URL encoding to the code and you'll see `%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B` in the word `escape`). Delete all the code and type it in manually. Sadikhasan, [**we already had this before**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624233/how-to-convert-sql-query-to-cakephp-query/24624359#comment38173098_24624359), I really don't know how you guys always mange to slip something like that in your code.

Comment: @BenedictRuban You obviously know how to use a keyboard, so just do what I've suggested, type in the code manually, char by char.